# How to edit input style by using ng-pattern

Tags: css, angularjs, regex, angularjs-ng-pattern

I made a small js [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rcupgp5r/)

I also add the code to the Stack overflow snippet but for some reason it doesn't work to me

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.my_model = ''
   $scope.my_regex = '/^[A-Za-z]+(\,[A-Za-z]+)*$/';
    $scope.my_placeHolder = 'write something';
}
```

```css
.invalid input[name=my_input]{   
  border: 2px solid red;
}


input[name=my_input] {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="contentForm">
    <input type="text"
         name="my_input"
         ng-class="{ 'invalid': contentForm['my_input'].$invalid }"
         ng-model="my_model"
         ng-pattern="{{my_regex}}"
         placeholder="{{my_placeHolder}}">
  </form>
</div>
```

I tried to use the code snippet but weren't working >,<

So, my goal is to edit the input border (let's make it red for purpose) if the input text doesn't pass the regex rule.

The regex should accept any comma separated string.

I tried a bunch of stuff, but I can't figure out what am i doing wrong.

UPDATE: REGEX EDITED

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: I updated my answer as per your regex and dummy text input

Comment: border should be red when pattern isn't matched.
Should use pattern from controller
Pattern should allow only characters strings separated by comma. Spaces allowed between strings and commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet, `( )*,( )*[a-zA-Z]+)*` regex is not valid. you can test your regex [here](http://www.regextester.com/30467) or other online tool. Here i tried with simple numeric regex and it is working fine.

```js
function formCtrl($scope){
     $scope.my_model = 'test,dfsdf,dfs'
    $scope.my_placeHolder = 'write something';
    $scope.my_pattern="/^[A-Za-z]+(\,[A-Za-z]+)*$/";// here you replace your regex which you want 
}
```

```css
.invalid{   
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.valid {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" >
    <input type="text" ng-model="my_model" name="my_input" ng-pattern="
    {{my_pattern}}" ng-class="{'invalid': myForm.my_input.$error.pattern, 'valid': !myForm.my_input.$error.pattern }"
    placeholder="{{my_placeHolder}}"
    />
    <span ng-show="myForm.my_input.$error.pattern">Not a valid input!</span>
   
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: @Koop4 May be this solution help you to solve your issue.

Comment: this actually works, but i don't really like the !important in the css style.

Comment: @Koop4 I have just updated code, as per you said i removed important from the css style. I hope, this is help it.

Answer (score 2):

If `ng-pattern` fails, which means the regex is not fulfilled, a class `ng-invalid-pattern` is added to the `<input>` element. This means that you should be able to add the the red border to an input field that isn't passing the `ng-pattern` with the following CSS:

```
input[name=my_input].ng-invalid-pattern{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: i tried to edit the jsfiddle by removing the ng class and adding the style u suggested but still doesn't work, could you try it too?

Comment: @Koop4 It's something wrong with your regex, I tried with a basic regex `/[A-Z]/` and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/rcupgp5r/1/

Comment: mmh, the regex seems to work tho, i even tried with ```[a-zA-Z]+( *, *[a-zA-Z]+)*``` 

What seems to not work is providing the regex using the controller. Can anyone realize what are we doing wrong?

Comment: @Koop4 Wrote a new regex for you. Hope it's ok. `/^[A-Za-z]+(\,[A-Za-z]+)*$/` in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rcupgp5r/2/

Comment: with the regex it works, but using it from pattern doesn't, even using the RegExp constructor. Am I missing anything?
Edit,, i used the previous regex since your wasn't accepting spaces between strings and comma.
here's the correct jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yhqjf6bv/

Comment: yes, both answer works, i ll approve the previous one since it also use the ng-pattern as required from question!
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try with This

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="contentForm">
    <input type="text"
         name="my_input"
         ng-class="{'invalid': contentForm['my_input'].$error.pattern  }"
         ng-model="my_model"
         ng-pattern="'( )*,( )*[a-zA-Z]+)*'"
         placeholder="{{my_placeHolder}}">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't tried it, but i m aiming to have the ng-pattern from scope anyway.  I edited my regex since it was wrongly copy pasted before, feel free to edit your snippet. thanks